# Gradle mysteriously running Build task?

Tags: gradle

This is challenging my sanity. I have the following `build.gradle`:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

defaultTasks 'build'

// not specifying .cmd on windows will attempt to
// run the extensionless executable which will fail
ext {
  npmCommand = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm'
  tscCommand = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'tsc.cmd' : 'tsc'
}

// Get the path for the locally installed binaries
task npmBin << {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        exec {
            executable = npmCommand
            args = ['bin']
            standardOutput = os
        }
        ext.binPath = os.toString().trim() + File.separator
    }
}

task copyVendor(type: Copy) {
  from 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
       'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
       'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js'
  into 'build/app/scripts/vendor'
}

task copyNonTS(type: Copy) {
  from('app') {
    exclude '**/*.ts', '**/*.js.map'
  }
    filter { line -> line.replaceAll('(node_modules\\/systemjs\\/dist)|(node_modules\\/angular2\\/bundles)', 'app/scripts/vendor') }
  into 'build/app'
}

// Install packages from package.json
task npm(type: Exec) {
    description = "Grab NodeJS dependencies (from package.json)"
    commandLine = [npmCommand, "install"]
    inputs.file "package.json"
    outputs.dir "node_modules"

    tasks.npmBin.execute()
}

task cleanDev(type: Delete) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  delete fileTree(dir: 'app', include: ['**/*.js', '**/*.js.map'])
}

task delOutput(type: Delete) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    println "DELETING"
    delete 'build/'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    cleanDev.execute()
    delOutput.execute()
}

task build(dependsOn: 'npm', type: Exec) {
    println "BUILDING"
    if (file(new File("${npmBin.binPath}${tscCommand}")).isFile()) {
        // runs non-globally installed tsc from node_modules
        commandLine "${npmBin.binPath}${tscCommand}"
    } else {
        // runs globally installed tsc
        commandLine = [tscCommand]
    }
  copyVendor.execute()
  copyNonTS.execute()
}
```

Somehow, when I run `gradle delOutput` I get the following output:

```
DELETING
BUILDING
:delOutput

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.012 secs
```

Why when I run this seemingly small, atomic, no-dependencies task does my build task run? It deletes my build folder then immediately calls for the build task to run again (as evident by the output "BUILDING").

What's happening here?

EDIT:

This [forum post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-does-a-type-exec-task-require-that-one-not-use/6871/4) agrees with what's being said here. However it seems that if I have a task of `type: Exec` then I have to specify `commandLine` during the configuration phase and doing so seems to always execute the command regardless of if I actually want to run the task. How do I only run the `commandLine` when the task is run?

Comment: `defaultTasks 'build'` might have something to do with this? Try commenting that line out.

Comment: I tried commenting it out but no difference. I think that only comes into play if you just run `gradle` and don't specify a task.

Comment: `task build(){` should be `task build()<<{`

Comment: same with your other task definitions.

Comment: That looks like it did the trick. What does `<<` really mean?

Comment: Now when I do try to build, I get `Execution failed for task ':build'.
> execCommand == null!`

Comment: updated my answer below

Comment: I see a lot of places where you're explictly calling taskName.execute(). These task dependencies would be better managed through `dependsOn`. I expected that those .execute()s are happening during the *configuration* phase of your Gradle build which is one of the roots of your problem.

Comment: See the 2nd section of this webpage for an explanation of the difference between configuration and execution phases of Gradle builds https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/potential_traps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

is short hand for

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

If you do not have `doLast`, the task will run in the configuration phase instead of when you invoke it explicitly.

Change your task definitions from `task build(){` to `task build()<<{`

Edit for your edit:

Would something like this work for you?

```
task hello {

    def commandline = 'something' //in the config phase

    doLast {
        println 'Executing!' //in the exec phase
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing so causes `gradle build` to fail. I'm told that `execCommand == null!`

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging. I thought I understood Gradle and everything that was being pointed out yesterday flew in the face of my understanding.  Who knew there was a configuration phase?!? Well, not me apparently. I apologize and you helped me set the record straight.

Comment: NP, I would be lying if I said gradle didn't, every now and then, challenge my entire understanding of how I thought things worked behind the scenes. Doesn't help that things are still changing around quite a bit!